# CSS is not applying & images are not loading properly after moving to new server - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, image, css

I have just moved a Magento ( v 1.9 ) store to a new server. Everything started working after changing database and base_url in core_config_data table. But theme is not applying.

Though I can see stylesheet is loaded in the resources tab in chrome and I can access the file by entering the url in browser.

like http://abcd.com/skin/frontend/default/em0089/css/styles.css

Here is the screenshot of the store

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to access the site admin ? If yes, then check if all paths are correctly set in there and proper theme is selected or not.

Comment: thanks @Prateek for replying. Yes I am able to log into admin. I have checked base_url is properly set and correct theme is also selected. Have also followed the permission from here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: What's the URL of your website ?

Comment: @DigitalPianism the website is http://indowesternpublishers.com/

Comment: I'd suggest double check permissions on the `app/design/` folders, your theme is getting picked up as the style files are getting loaded, but Magento is unable to pickup the layout and templates from your theme and thus loading the base theme.

Comment: @Prateek will check that